# Rendering a page fragment when using this.href

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to load only a div from a page using .load(), but as I am using 'this.href' as the page url I'm unsure how I can get just the div from that page.

Heres my code, I want to retrieve a div with id of 'playerForm'. Currently its returning the whole page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".arrow a").click(function(event) {
    $("#nominatedPlayer").load(this.href + '#playerForm');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give the selector a context of the loaded page. To do this provide some sort of html as the second parameter in the selector.

```
$("#nominatedPlayer").load(this.href, function(response){
     console.log($('#playerForm', response).html())
});
```

This will still load the entire page, but will select out the div's html that you want

Answer (score 1):

`this.href + '#playerForm'` will return you the entire page, scrolled to that position.

There's no way to just load a portion out of a web page.  You'll need to take the segment you need, and put it in a separate htm file, and call load on *that*